# Label change color when clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA/Excel that user clicks on labels (Active X - Text Label) to perform some actions. The label property is BackStyle Transparent, but when the user click, the label keep opaque, like white or whatever the BackColor property is set.

How can I keep transparent when user click on the label?

[image: One example of this label]

Comment: A code sample would come in handy.

Comment: It's more about the Property. Some of the simplest codes that run after the click is: `Private Sub Label5_Click()
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 108
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
End Sub

Private Sub Label6_Click()
UserForm1.Show

End Sub

Private Sub Label7_Click()
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 21
End Sub`

Comment: What kind of label?   A cell comment, a chart label, a callout shape?  Could you _edit_ your question with any new info please - edit button is just under the tags.

Comment: Why does it have to be a label? From the screenshot I don't see why it couldn't be just a texbox `Shape` assigned to a macro.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon to be honest, I didn't know about it.... But right now it's kind of impossible to redo it, it's so many labels in the entire project =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use an ActiveX control for this. Any `Shape` can be assigned to a macro, so instead of having `Click` event handlers for ActiveX labels like so:

```
Private Sub Label2_Click()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Make the handlers public, give them a meaningful name:

```
Public Sub BuscaPorPalavraChave()
    'do stuff
End Sub
```

Replace the labels with `TextBox` shapes - make the shape fill and border transparent, right-click the shape, and select "assign macro" - then pick `BuscaPorPalavraChavre`. Done!

[image: textbox shape made to look just like a label]

*Rinse & Repeat* for every label. I know, painful - but worth it!

That navigation UI looks very nice BTW =)

Comment: @GuiWeb as a bonus you get to be able to rotate the shape to match the tilting of the panels, *and* you get the "hand" cursor for free =)

Comment: I wish I asked that in the beginning lol. I done the replace of Private Sub to Public Sub and will be just 176 shapes to change #PanicMode kkkkkkk but, yeah, I must agree: the hand cursor is a really great bonus

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a different solution in case you have faced a related problem, like the transparency/opaque problem when executing a macro hovering over a transparent label but that becomes opaque when clicking on it.

The workaround consists basically in changing the visibility status when hovering in and out. It might be counterintuitive at first (Because you are making disappear the same label you are using to execute the macro) but it works really well. Let's assume we have two Active X labels overlap. Label1 is the bigger one and label2 is the smaller one, completely contained in Label1. The code I used is like:

```
Private Sub Label2_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Label2.Visible = False 
Label1.Visible = True
### Put your code in here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Then as you hover out label2, and assuming the labels are correctly overlap, you will hover over Label 1, now visible because you "activated it", and the following code is executed

```
Private Sub Label1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Label2.Visible = True
Label1.Visible = False
### Put your code in here
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Please bear in mind that you need to have a figure or button in between the two Active x labels, otherwise you will get a strange result because in the exact moment you hover over Label 2, it will disappear, leaving Label 1 beneath it which will also disappear as soon as you move, makin Label 2 appear again and ... you get the idea. This will not break the excel file but will make it make strange things like blinking or delaying the mouse movement. To prevent thus. I recommend to have that shape as a safe zone.

Hope this helps.